# Rails link_to not automagically using request.format as extension in links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, format, link-to

I'm setting request.format = :mobile within an ApplicationController before_filter.

```
before_filter :some_filter
def some_filter
   request.format = :mobile
end
```

I have this mapping in routes:

```
map.my_list '/my_list.:format', :controller => "of_no", :action => "significance"
```

When I do the following:

```
<%= link_to "My List", my_list_path %>
```

I get the following (ACTUAL below):

```
<a href="/my_list">My List</a> <!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM -->
```

I want this to be (EXPECTED below):

```
<a href="/my_list.mobile">My List</a> <!-- THIS IS THE EXPECTED -->
```

However, if I do the following:

```
<%= link_to "My List", my_list_path(:format => "mobile") %>
```

Then I get the EXPECTED result, but doing this to every "link_to" is not a viable solution.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: If specifying the format in the helper is not viable, how to you want to set it?

Comment: (I edited my post) Do I need to specify the format within the link_to helper.  I thought that this would be implicit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to specify the format in the helper if you want the URL to show my_list.mobile. However, if your filter doesn't use the URL to determine the format, and you're setting the format in your controller, why would you need it in the URL too? Your controller should respond to the .mobile format without it in the URL when request.format is overridden.

You could probably get away with removing the `.:format` part of your route definition and just rely on the request object being set.

Comment: The example setup was just to show the bare minimum setup for someone else to encounter the problem.

I'm working with will_paginate, and it inherently (and correctly I believe) renders the pagination links with the .mobile extension (under the setup above).

I was wondering if I was doing something wrong, or missing something, effectively prevented "link_to" from exhibiting the same behavior.